# I am fail to get string value from an array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get the `departmentName` displayed but I always get null value from it, but I am able to get the `departmentID`, this confuse me.

```
template: `
   <h3>
     you selected department with id = {{departmentName}},{{departmentID}} //here only show the ID but cant show the Name,the Name value is null from console that I saw.
   </h3>
```

```
export class DepartmentDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public departmentID;
  public departmentName;

ngOnInit() 
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params:ParamMap) => {
        let id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
        let name = params.get('name'); // I think here is the problem why I cant get the name value

        this.departmentID = id;
        this.departmentName = name;

      });
    }
```

```
//array from other component

export class DepartmentListComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedId;

  departments = [
    {"id":1,"name":"Angular"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Node"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Ruby"},
  ]
```

Comment: can you show us the console.log(params)

Comment: You may require to parse your params to json. Do json.parse(params) and then try accessing name and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , After a little bit of adjustment I can get the value of name

this is the original path and after I add in :name into the path then I am able to get the name
( But I am sure that this is not the perferct answer as I encounter other problem afterward,anyone who has other answer please feel free to share it)

```
{path : 'departments/:id',component:DepartmentDetailComponent}
```

```
{path : 'departments/:id/:name',component:DepartmentDetailComponent},
```

(I added in the name value in the router.navigate in the array list also)

```
 onSelect(department){
    this.router.navigate(['/departments',department.id,department.name]);
  }
```

Comment: If this is a separate question, ask a new one. If your original question has been answered. At least post the answer so that other users may see it.